# Make HTML 5 range slider change based on value selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, range

I want to create a custom marker on HTML5 range.

The actual circle marker you drag I want to be able to change the design of this as they move and change the value. The example below moves from 1 through to 10. I want to change the colour as they change the value.

Any ideas?

```html
<label for=weight>Party Scale</label>
<input type=range id=weight min=0 value=0 max=10 step=1>
```

Thanks,

Lewis

Comment: Can you post what have you tried  ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
What is "this" ? => what do you want to change when the user  ? 
What is the value ?
what is they move ? you mean "while they drag it" ?

Comment: Added as requested. It's the marker you move which I am looking to change as you move it along (i.e. change the value).

Comment: Ok I have post an answer, hope it help. 
A little example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/rv9xqwq6/1/

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 Ranges are limited. You are better using a plugin like [noUiSlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/), it has many more options, especially for what your trying to achieve.

Here is an example I made with it:

[image]

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pjxg7p1o/)

JS

```
var rangeSlider = document.getElementById('weight');

noUiSlider.create(rangeSlider, {
    start: [ 0 ],
    range: {
        'min': [  1 ],
        'max': [ 10 ]
    }
});

rangeSlider.noUiSlider.on('slide', function(values, handle){
    var v = values[handle],
        s = v * 10,
        l = 50;

    $(rangeSlider).find('.noUi-handle').css({"background-color":"hsl(10," + s + "%," + l +"%)"})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding:

```
 -webkit-appearance: none;
```

Then you can change

```
 background-color: blue;
```

A little example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/rv9xqwq6/1/

Comment: He wants to change the "handle," rather than the background of the range itself, from my reading of the question.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to reset the appearance of the input range, at least for webkit and gecko based browsers:

```
#myRange {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
#myRange::-moz-range-thumb{
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
#myRange::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

You have also to add some rules, because now the appearance of the element is not defined anymore (see the fiddle below)

then, you can listen for cursor moves with the `input` event, and add a css rule in a dynamicaly-created style sheet:

```
$("#myRange").on("input", function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.value > 50) 
        var rule= "background:red";
    else 
        var rule= "yellow"

    sheet.textContent = 
            "#myRange::-webkit-slider-thumb{ "+rule+" } " +
            "#myRange::-ms-thumb{ "+rule+" } " +
            "#myRange::-moz-range-thumb{  "+rule+" } ";

})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rv9xqwq6/8/

some useful links:

http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html
http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/jEXjVE
http://trevan.co/custom-range-inputs-with-css-javascript/